# fatal error: opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello all I am trying to use opencv-c++ API (version 4.4.0) which I have built from source. It is installed in /usr/local/ and I was simply trying to load and display an image using the following code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    std::string image_path = "13.jpg";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imreadmulti(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(img.empty())
    {
        std::cout<<"COULD NOT READ IMAGE"<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    imshow("Display Window", img);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile it throws the following error during compilation -

```
In file included from /CLionProjects/opencvTest/main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
```

My Cmake is as follows -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(opencvTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
include_directories("/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/")
add_executable(opencvTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(opencvTest PUBLIC "/usr/local/lib/")
```

I do not know what am I doing wrong here.. This might be a noob question, But I ahev just started using opencv in C++

Comment: You need `/usr/local/include/opencv4` to be in your include directories not `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2`

Comment: Taking a guess, your path is incorrect. try this `include_directories("/usr/local/include/")`. You shouldn't have opencv4/opencv2 in both your include path and in your include directives. The include directive starts where the include path stops.

Comment: @john the error I think is actually generated in `opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp` where it is not able to find `"opencv_modules"` even though they are in the same directory. I tried your suggestion as well and it did not work, however I do not think it would actually make a difference.. I may be wrong about it though

Comment: What worked for me was: sudo cp -r /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2 /usr/include/

Comment: @Owl your suggestions works. I got a second suggestion, who helped me too. Add in the `tasks.json` the following at "args:" `"-I/usr/local/include/opencv4",`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to just include_directories path till `/usr/local/opencv4` and it works perfectly.

However, the best way I believe is to use the `find_package` function. I updated my Cmake to the following and it takes care of linking during build.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(opencvTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(opencvTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(opencvTest ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: This is indeed a better and more proper `CMake` solution.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It is exactly what I have been looking for for hours...

Comment: Thanks! In my case, "include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})" did worked!

Answer (score 1):

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

it should look like that.

relatively, the header search paths should be:
/usr/local/include/opencv4

Comment: Please, use proper code formatting options available in StackOverflow editor when publishing an answer or a question.