# How Can I Convert Image .png to string in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to using C++. I am trying to convert an image to a string (I need to convert an image to a buffer).

So I use the "opencv" library. I try it but it doesn't work. When I execute my program this way:

> g++ testpng.cpp -o testpng

This is the error in the terminal:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory
   48 | #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I need help to solve this error, or a working example to convert an image (.png) to a string, please!!

Comment: This sounds like a linking problem. Do you use Make or CMake files or do you use an IDE with linking options?

Comment: Please check if your issue is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63456129/18667225

Comment: what kinda string? just the bytes in the file (image is compressed), or do you want pixels?

Comment: so I don´t know how i use make file with programm .cpp .

Comment: I want the image to a string types not a pixel

Comment: "below you will find my program" I believe you forgot to add it to your question. Also, calling g++ does not execute your program, it merely tries to compile the file you passed as argument.

Comment: Perhaps you’d like to use an image converter program to convert your image from PNG format to XPM format.  One of the interesting qualities of an XPM image file is that it is also a valid C file that can be directly compiled into your program, and the image data can be accessed by other parts of the program, as a char array.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap

Comment: You can use cv::imencode to generate a byte array from an image. If you want a displayable string you might want to use hexcode instead.

Comment: @Raavgo "*This sounds like a linking problem*" - no, it is clearly a compiler error, not a linker error.  The compiler is not able to find the `opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp` header file. This is a configuration problem, the compiler is not being told where to look for the `opencv2` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to load an image and then retrieve data from it, use the `stb` header library. It's simple to use, no binary libraries, only header files required. Simply [download it from github](https://github.com/nothings/stb) and then include the `stb_image.h` file in your project.