# Why do I get an error when compiling opencv code with make even if the particular missing files exist?

Tags: opencv, makefile

I've got the following `makefile`:

```
OBJS:=  main.o

CV_LIBS:= -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann

main: $(OBJS) 
      g++ $(OBJS) $(CV_LIBS) -O3 -ffast-math -o main -Wall -g

main.o: main.h
        g++ -c main.cpp -Wall -g
```

My `main.h` file has the following line:

```c
#include <opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:47:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
   47 | #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
```

I have tried the following as well with no luck:

```c
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
```

Error:

```
main.h:4:10: fatal error: opencv2/objdetect.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I can confirm there is an `objdetect.hpp` in both:

- `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/` and
- `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp`

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455427/fatal-error-opencv2-opencv-modules-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory-include-ope), but unfortunately I'm not using `cmake`. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the compile line that make prints out (which you didn't include in your question), it's pretty straightforward why you get this error.

The compile line, that compiles `main.c` into `main.o`, looks like this:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -Wall -g
```

You can clearly see that there is no reference to the directories you need to include header files here.

Your makefile has this:

```
CV_LIBS:= -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

where you are combining *compiler* flags, such as `-I`, with *linker* flags, such as `-L` and `-l` in the same variable, calling them all "LIBS", and adding them only to the link line.

You need to put the compiler flags into the compile command, and the linker flags into the link command:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -I/usr/local/include

CV_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann

main: $(OBJS) 
        g++ $(OBJS) $(CV_LIBS) -O3 -ffast-math -o main -Wall -g

main.o: main.h
        g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -c main.cpp -Wall -g
```

FYI, it's more correct for you to use `#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>` in your source code, not `#include <opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp>`