# Setting up cmake with C++ and openCV: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am very new to C++ and cmake (that means: I started yesterday) and I am stuck trying to include OpenCV. It might be a complete rookie mistake that I made somewhere during installation as well, so I am really hoping for your ideas and experience.
So, this is the code I am trying to run:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << CV_VERSION << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
main.cpp:1:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

I had a look at [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455427/fatal-error-opencv2-opencv-modules-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory-include-ope) and updated my CMake file to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(myproject VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

add_executable(myproject main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myproject ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

UPDATE: Meanwhile, I added a couple of `json` files, as suggested [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/vs-code-with-opencv-c-on-windows-10-explained-256418442c52).But I am not exactely sure if I adjusted them correctly to my case.

So this is my `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/opencv/sources/include",
                "C:/opencv/build/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

But that didn't solve the problem either. Any ideas on what is wrong? As I said, I am completely new to this so it might be something really easy/stupid. ^^°

Those are the locations on my PC where Cmake and openCV are stored, in case that is relevant :

```
C:\opencv
C:\Program Files\CMake
```

Comment: Check the value of `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` and make sure it points to where you expect and that it contains `opencv2/opencv.hpp`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for that. I checked and I found two things: ```OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = C:/opencv/build/include``` which seems to be fine, because there is this file ```C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp``` BUT there is also a file with the same name here: ```C:\opencv\sources\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp``` and now I am confused which one I need and how to link it properly...

Comment: the next thing to check is what the compiler commands actually are, if you're using `make` you can run `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I added some information, maybe that helps?

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` only configures intellisense, it won't fix compiler errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, meanwhile I found a way to make it work.
I originally followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9HBM1m_EMU) to set everything up. But upon running the script using the “play button” I encountered the error mentioned in the title and the description, even though the files were in the indicated location and all paths were correctly included. And I still cannot do it this way but there is another way and maybe there are more beginners like me who are not aware of this, which is why I want to share it.

In Windows, press `SHIFT+CRTL+P` and type in “CMake” in the window that pops up and you will find the `CMake: Build` command. Click it and it will generate an executable file for you, which in my case was located in `build/Debug/`. If you run this executable from the console, it works (provided your code doesn’t contain any errors).

It is kind of a workaround, because at least according to the mentioned tutorial there should be a simpler way to run the code, but at least I can continue working now.

It would still be interesting to know why it doesn’t find the files when I run the script directly in VSCode, so if anyone has an idea, please share it, it will help me and others that are struggling with the same (beginner?) problems.